# Determine if a list is in descending order

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that will test whether or not a list is in decending order.  This is what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to be working for all lists.

I used the list `[9,8,5,1,4,3,2]` and it returned `'true'`.

I can't seem to figure out where my mistake is.

```
def ordertest(A):
    n = len(A)
    for i in range(n):
        if A[i] >= A[i+1]:
            return 'true'
        else:
            return 'false'
```

Comment: `list(reversed(sorted(lis)))==lis`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should rather do the reverse check (As soon as you get `A[i] < A[i+1]`, return false

```
def ordertest(A):
    for i in range( len(A) - 1 ):
        if A[i] < A[i+1]:
            return False
        return True
```

Comment: I tried this, and when I tested the list [9,5,2] I got the following error message:

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: It feels really unpythonic (not to mention probably slow) to iterate by index access.

Comment: @phihag.. You can remove your downvote.. If you did one.. I have edited the code..

Comment: @RohitJain Huh? The question is +3/-0, and that would be such a tiny flaw that I wouldn't downvote it, and wouldn't expect anyone else to.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  If you don't mind explaining, why did this change in the range fix the problem?

Comment: @phihag.. OK. I admit, this might be slow.. But I still don't know everything about python.. can't help it.. I just corrected the logical problem in the code..

Comment: @user1653420.. Because when you reach the last index.. A[i+1] will go out of range.. So, you need to go till 2nd last index..

Comment: @user1653420 The last item in `range(len(A))` is `i = len(A)-1`, and accessing `i+1 = len(A)-1+1 = len(A)` fails.

Comment: @RohitJain.. Thank you so much, this is exactly the answer I was looking for.  I appreciate the others who suggested other solutions, but I was looking for something that would fix the code that I had already written.

Comment: @user1653420.. You're welcome.. But you should see other's answer also.. That might be optimal than using a loop to iterate.. I personally feel so..

Comment: @user1653420 My answer has been pretty heavily buried here - but please take a look. It is the most concise, clear and efficient option. If you are writing Python, people will appreciate you writing it in a Pythonic way - it makes everyone's lives easier.

Comment: I agree that's unpythonic, but the OP is asking what is wrong with his code, so you sould first answer to his question and **then** post a more pythonic solution.

Comment: @PaoloMoretti Of course, but others had already answered that question when I posted mine - there was no point repeating it - I was focussing on the best way of doing the task at hand. I'm not saying that this shouldn't be the accepted answer, just that, for reference, mine is a more Pythonic solution.

Comment: This seems to be rather efficient, actually.  I benchmarked it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12734223/722332

Comment: @zigg.. So, what difference did izip made?? Of course a huge time difference, but how??

Comment: See this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734178/python-function-to-determine-is-a-list-is-in-decending-order#comment17229984_12734223  `zip` is apparently making a copy of the list.

Comment: The reason is that in Python 2.x, ``zip()`` isn't lazy - it produces a list, meaning that the whole list is computed regardless of whether or not it is used. I normally use 3.x, where ``zip()`` gives a generator, and did say that ``izip()`` should be used under 2.x.

Answer (score 39):

You can do this easily with [a generator expression](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY&list=UUAuqj5Bs5mTTl1mIVDmuAlw&index=1&feature=plcp) and [the `all()` builtin](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/functions.html#all):

```
all(earlier >= later for earlier, later in zip(seq, seq[1:]))
```

For example:

```
>>> seq = [9, 8, 5, 1, 4, 3, 2] 
>>> all(earlier >= later for earlier, later in zip(seq, seq[1:]))
False
>>> seq = [9, 8, 5, 4, 3, 2] 
>>> all(earlier >= later for earlier, later in zip(seq, seq[1:]))
True
```

This should be nice and fast as it avoids python-side loops, short circuits nicely (if you use `itertools.izip()` in 2.x), and is nice and clear and readable (avoiding looping over indices, for example).

Note that a generic solution for all iterators (not just sequences) is possible too:

```
first, second = itertools.tee(iterable)
next(second)
all(earlier >= later for earlier, later in zip(first, second))
```

Comment: @Lattyware.. +1 I loved your logic so much.. :)

Comment: You may be interested in my benchmark http://stackoverflow.com/a/12734223/722332 -- seems this may be rather slow.

Comment: I ran it again using `izip`, and it's now the fastest solution.  Sorry about that :-)

Answer (score 8):

Here is a concise way to perform this test that uses `all()`:

```
def ordertest(A):
    return all(A[i] >= A[i+1] for i in range(len(A)-1))
```

Examples:

```
>>> ordertest([9,8,5,1,4,3,2])
False
>>> ordertest([9,8,5,4,3,2,1])
True
```

Comment: It's not very pythonic to loop over indices.

Comment: @Lattyware Usually true, but this is more efficient than the slice/zip method in your answer, and still very readable.

Comment: I must say I disagree on the readability front, and I would imagine the efficiency gain is negligible.

Comment: I plugged this into my benchmark at http://stackoverflow.com/a/12734223/722332 and it took 0.597107172012 seconds.  It beats walking, but was still slower than using `izip`--though `zip` is indeed quite slow.

Comment: Really nice and understandable oneliner. Who cares about pythonicity if it is fast and easy to understand.

Answer (score 5):

I originally proposed using [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted), and it was pointed out to me that [it may be less efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734178/python-function-to-determine-is-a-list-is-in-decending-order#comment17200504_12734223) than your iteration.

```
>>> l = [3, 1, 2]
>>> l == sorted(l, reverse=True)
False
>>> l = [3, 2, 1]
>>> l == sorted(l, reverse=True)
True
```

So I benchmarked [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12734211/722332), mine, [Lattyware's generator solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12734228/722332), and the same with [`itertools.izip`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip).  I intentionally used a case that I believed would favor my `sorted` solution: a list that is only out-of-order at the end.  These benchmarks were performed on Python 2.7.1 on an old OpenBSD machine.

**sorted.py**

```
import time
l = list(reversed(range(99998) + [99999, 99998]))
start = time.time()
for count in range(100):
    l == sorted(l)
end = time.time()
print('elapsed: {}'.format(end - start))
```

**walk.py**

```
import time
def ordertest(l):
    for i in range(len(l) - 1):
        if l[i] < l[i+1]:
            return False
    return True
l = list(reversed(range(99998) + [99999, 99998]))
start = time.time()
for count in range(100):
    ordertest(l)
end = time.time()
print('elapsed: {}'.format(end - start))
```

**generator.py**

```
import time
l = list(reversed(range(99998) + [99999, 99998]))
start = time.time()
for count in range(100):
    all(earlier >= later for earlier, later in zip(l, l[1:]))
end = time.time()
print('elapsed: {}'.format(end - start))
```

**izip.py**

```
import itertools
import time
l = list(reversed(range(99998) + [99999, 99998]))
start = time.time()
for count in range(100):
    all(earlier >= later for earlier, later in itertools.izip(l, l[1:]))
end = time.time()
print('elapsed: {}'.format(end - start))
```

The results:

```
$ python sorted.py
elapsed: 1.0896859169
$ python walk.py
elapsed: 0.641126155853
$ python generator.py
elapsed: 4.79061508179
$ python izip.py
elapsed: 0.363445997238
```

As pointed out in the comments to this answer, the generator expression is likely made slow by `zip` making a copy of the list.  Using `izip` beats all.

Comment: That wastes a lot of CPU time for no particular reason--especially with a long list.

Comment: Does it?  I would expect `sorted` to be implemented more efficiently than a `for` loop iterating, comparing the order of items.

Comment: The `for` loop can bail early, as soon as any element is larger than its predecessor.  Even if `sorted` used a heap (which it doesn't, you'd still be looking at O(N*log(N)) runtime, versus O(N) for the simple `for` loop, making it slower in the common case.

Comment: @BenjaminPollack Your feedback prompted me to run some benchmarks, which I've edited into my answer.  You were right, even in a case I expected would give me an edge!

Comment: `zip` creates a copy list, `izip` does not. There will be significant impact, I suppose.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using indices, you can iterate over the input:

```
def ordertest(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    prev = next(it)
    for e in it:
        if e > prev:
            return False
        prev = e
    return True
```

Note that it's a bad idea to return the strings `'true'` and `'false'`. Instead, you can use Python's built-in [booleans](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values).

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is

```
n=len(A)
for i in range(n - 1):
    if A[i]<=A[i+1]:
        return 'false'
return 'true
```

Try to execute your code in your head. At the first iteration, if A[i] is greater than A[i + 1] you return true, else you return false. You never go futher in your list.

The good solution is to test your condition, and if in false at anytime, return false. But if its right, this doesnt mean that the rest of the list is, and you want to test each of your values.

And as you test A[i + 1], you dont want to go at the end of your list, but at the `n - 1` item of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
n=len(l)
c=0
for i in range(n - 1):
    if l[i]<l[i+1]:
        c+=1
    if c==1:
        break
if(c==1):
    return False
return True
```

To check without any error and to check that too correctly this function using a counter is the best. As soon as the loop runs and the iterate becomes 1 it breaks no more need of searching. it will return false else true.
Thank you!