# Product with descreasing values

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension, python-itertools

I have a 3 lists :

```
a = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6]
b = [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
c = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

I need to get all the permutations obtained with `itertools.product()`, BUT only if the values are decreasing:

```
[10, 8, 6] # is good
[6, 8, 4]  # is not good, since 8 > 6
```

Is there a simple way to do it or should I go with list comprehension and conditions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with a list comprehension by looping over the`itertools.product` iterator and extracting only those returned items that are sorted in reverse:

```
[item for item in product(a,b,c) if sorted(item, reverse = True) == list(item)]
```

Example:

```
from itertools import product
a = [10,9,8,7,6]
b = [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
c = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
[item for item in product(a,b,c) if sorted(item, reverse = True) == list(item)]
# [(10, 8, 6), (10, 8, 5), (10, 8, 4), (10, 8, 3), (10, 8, 2) ...continues
```

Answer (score 2):

You can refer following code which does not have list comprehensions:

```
from itertools import product
a = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6]
b = [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
c = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
for result in product(a,b,c):
    if sorted(result, reverse = True) == list(result):
            print result
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple one line solution

```
>>> mylist = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6]
>>> all(earlier >= later for earlier, later in zip(mylist, mylist[1:]))
True
>>> mylist = [10, 9, 7, 8, 6]
>>> all(earlier >= later for earlier, later in zip(mylist, mylist[1:]))
False
```

I found this here:

[Determine if a list is in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734178/determine-if-a-list-is-in-descending-order)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use list comprehensions for some reason:

```
def decreasing(l):
    return all(a >= b for a, b in zip(l[:-1], l[1:]))


filter(decreasing, product(a, b, c))
```